# View doesn't change when clicking a row - xcode ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I created a `UITableViewController` inside of a container in a `UIViewController`.

Everything works fine until I click on a cell in order to view a user's information.

When I click the row is supposed to go to a view that contains tabs, but it's not doing this (*it stays on the page of the table*).

I know it calls the function below since I put an NSLog in there and when I click a row it gets displayed.

Can someone please help me? Thank you!

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
  UINavigationController *tabController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabNav"];
tabController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem! For some strange reason I had to do change these lines:

UINavigationController *tabController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabNav"];
tabController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];

To these lines:

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabNav"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

In other words, it wasn't recognizing self.storyboard... Anyways, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Before you call:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
```

You have to add the `UINavigationController` - tabController to the view hierarchy.

// EXTENDED

Try this,:

```
     UINavigationController *tabController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabNav"];
    [tabController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    //try wit this line if this will not work
    //tabController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;  
    [self.view addSubview:tabController.view];
    [self addChildViewController:tabController];
    [tabController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
```

Comment: How can I do this? I mean, I did the same procedure for a previous view and it worked fine...

Comment: The idea works, but since the table is in a tab, when I use this it opens the tab bar that I call inside of this tab.